# POST a form in Facebook iFrame application does not work

Tags: facebook

My application has "survived" many Facebook API changes, to the point where it's quite messy.

Anyway: I'm no longer able to POST a simple HTML form. The entire page reloads and no data is saved.

I've tried several things. Changing the "action" url to include several Facebook parameters, changing the target (canvas_iframe) but to no avail.

Has anyone else encountered problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

try to write absolute path in "action". Its not important include Facebook parameter

Answer (score 0):

Give site url("www.example.com/") as the value of the action attribute rather the Canvas URL(http://appifylabs.com/facebook/yourapp/processform.php)

e.g

if processform.php is the script that will manipulate your form so give the value

```
site_url = "www.example.com/";

action="<?php echo site_url; ?>processform.php"
```